# Is there a way to remove the Adobe border from an embedded PDF object?

Tags: css, html, object, pdf

I'm trying to remove the standard PDF frame from an embedded PDF on my page. I'd like just the PDF to show up without the toolbar on top and thick black frame from the page. I don't want the print, save, or anything to effect the look of the page. Below is the code I am using:

```
<object data="update404.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="693" height="1130">
</object>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using object to embed PDF documents is not recommend - it will render different results in different devices and browsers and there is no way to make sure that it will look like you intend to. Have a look at the following projects for a better way to embed your project

**PDF.JS**
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

**FlexPaper**
http://flexpaper.devaldi.com

Answer (score 2):

Check out PDF Object:

http://pdfobject.com/examples/simplest.html

http://pdfobject.com/

This should let you accomplish what you wanted across all browsers.